# Is it possible to implement flow control for CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy

**Is it possible to use `writeValue` with type `CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse` and still have some flow control to avoid sending data faster than BLE stack manages to actually send it out?** Currently it works on Android but not on iOS.

The long story.

I have previously implemented duplex communication channel over BLE on Android. It is basically using two ATT characteristics - one is write/writeWithoutResponse and the other is notifiable.

On Android, even when I use writeWithoutResponse, Android sends me `onCharacteristicWrite` callback to signal that the data packet has at least reached BLE stack, and in this callback I send out the next data packet with size of current ATT_MTU-3 bytes.

This works fine, the data reaches the target intact and I can achieve transfer speeds about 10 KB/s.

But on iOS there is a problem. When using `writeValue` with type `CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse`, iOS (at least iOS 8) does not call `didWriteValueForCharacteristic` and this is intended and documented behavior. Thus I have no way of knowing if the data packet has reached BLE stack. The best I can is to call `writeValue` in a loop. Also, `writeValue` seems to be non blocking (async). As the result, not all of my data reaches the peripheral device. In the logs I see that the incoming data stream is stopped too soon. My guess is that if I call `writeValue` too fast, iOS is just carelessly overwriting previous cached writable characteristic value and thus misses some data bytes in between.

If I use `writeValue` with `CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse`, it works fine, and what's strange - it works fine even if I ignore `didWriteValueForCharacteristic` and just call `writeValue` in a loop. It seems, with `CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse` iOS is doing some internal housekeeping and uses BLE acknowledgments to avoid overwriting current value of the characteristic, therefore the data is being sent in order and without any losses.

Of course, I don't expect to get reliable writes using `CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse`, but at least make it work for most cases. If it works on Android, then why shouldn't it work on iOS?

Comment: Andoid and iOS have different BLE Stack implementations. What you could do is add a delay between `CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse ` writes and see if that is faster than writing using `CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse `

Comment: @Aris - thanks, that is what I was afraid of - that I'll have to experiment with hacky delay timers and find something that works more or less reliably and then test for the iOS versions requested by my customer. Each iOS version might have different best timings because of internal BLE connection management differences...

Comment: Yes, also there could be differences across different devices. I would go ahead and use `CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse` and take the performance hit.

Comment: You have to look at the essential difference between writing with and without a response.  Writing without a response (in iOS at least) has the implication that your write is "best effort".  If it doesn't get there, then that is OK (or at least you will deal with it at a higher layer).  Write with a response is guaranteed delivery/guaranteed notification of failure.  So you either need to use write with response or implement error checking/recovery in your own protocol

Comment: @Paulw11, yes, I understand that. The main complaint is that on Android writing without response works much more reliable than on iOS. It seems, Android tries to avoid overwriting characteristic value while the previous value has not been yet sent out, but iOS carelessly overwrites it, even when it clearly knows that previous value hasn't yet been sent out. Oh, Apple...

Answer (score 3):

Apple's implementation kind of sucks. All other implementations I've seen have proper flow control. What you could do if you don't want to implement some advanced TCP-like layer on top of BLE is to simply stick with Write Without Response packets but send each 10th packet or so as a Write With Response. Then you won't (with high probability) not get any packet drops. This will probably only be a small performance decrease. You should also increase the MTU to increase the throughput even further.